Chromium build can't find crate
When I build Chromium 126.0.6478.3, I get the following error
[1404/60934] RUST local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libstd_std.rlib
FAILED: local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libstd_std.rlib
"C:/program1/depot_tools/bootstrap-2@3_11_8_chromium_35_bin/python3/bin/python3.exe" "../../build/rust/rustc_wrapper.py" --target-windows --rustc=../../third_party/rust-toolchain/bin/rustc --depfile=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libstd_std.rlib.d --rsp=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libstd_std.rlib.rsp --  -Clinker=..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\bin\lld-link.exe --crate-name std ../../third_party/rust-toolchain/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/lib.rs --crate-type rlib --cfg=backtrace_in_libstd -Zforce-unstable-if-unmarked @gen/build/rust/std/rules/std/cargo_flags.rs "--cfg=feature=\"addr2line\"" "--cfg=feature=\"backtrace\"" "--cfg=feature=\"gimli-symbolize\"" "--cfg=feature=\"miniz_oxide\"" "--cfg=feature=\"object\"" "--cfg=feature=\"panic_unwind\"" "--cfg=feature=\"profiler\"" "--cfg=feature=\"profiler_builtins\"" "--cfg=feature=\"std_detect_dlsym_getauxval\"" "--cfg=feature=\"std_detect_file_io\"" --edition=2021 -Coverflow-checks=on -Cdefault-linker-libraries -Zdep-info-omit-d-target -Zmacro-backtrace -Zremap-cwd-prefix=. --target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc -Cembed-bitcode=no -Clto=no -Cpanic=abort -Zpanic_abort_tests --cfg "cr_rustc_revision=\"31e6e8c6c5b6ce62656c922c7384d3376018c980-2-llvmorg-19-init-9433-g76ea5feb\"" -g -Ccontrol-flow-guard=nochecks -Clink-arg=/nodefaultlib:msvcrt.lib -Clink-arg=msvcrtd.lib --cap-lints=allow -Dunsafe_op_in_unsafe_fn -Dwarnings -Aunused-imports --sysroot=local_rustc_sysroot --emit=dep-info=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libstd_std.rlib.d,link -o local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libstd_std.rlib -Ldependency=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib -Clink-arg=../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/clang/19/lib/windows/clang_rt.builtins-x86_64.lib --extern alloc=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/liballoc_alloc.rlib --extern compiler_builtins=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libcompiler_builtins_compiler_builtins.rlib --extern core=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libcore_core.rlib --extern cfg_if=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libcfg_if_cfg_if.rlib --extern hashbrown=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libhashbrown_hashbrown.rlib --extern panic_abort=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libpanic_abort_panic_abort.rlib --extern panic_unwind=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libpanic_unwind_panic_unwind.rlib --extern unwind=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libunwind_unwind.rlib --extern rustc_demangle=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/librustc_demangle_rustc_demangle.rlib --extern std_detect=local_rustc_sysroot/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/lib/libstd_detect_std_detect.rlib LDFLAGS RUSTENV OUT_DIR=../../../../../../../../../out/vs_dev/gen/build/rust/std/rules/std CFG_DISABLE_UNSTABLE_FEATURES=0 STD_ENV_ARCH=x86_64 CARGO_PKG_VERSION=0.0.0 CARGO_PKG_NAME=std "CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION=The Rust Standard Library" CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR=.
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `libc`
   --> ../../third_party/rust-toolchain/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/lib.rs:438:1
    |
438 | extern crate libc;
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate

error: aborting due to 1 previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.

All I can say for sure is that I've run gclient sync correctly.
And when I build lower versions like 126.0.6438.0 it compiles fine.
I have already run gclient sync.
PS D:\chromium\src> gclient sync -D --force
Updating depot_tools...
Syncing projects: 100% (170/170), done.
Running hooks: 100% (165/165), done.

I want to know how to solve this problem.
